# what's the prob with this code?

Tags: c++, linux, vector, casting, execvp

Am trying to call evecvp() with these arguments:

```
vector<string>subcommand;
void parse(char *str)
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *cmd1=(char *)malloc(sizeof(300));

    cmd1=strtok(str," ");
    while(cmd1!=NULL)
    {
        subcommand.push_back(cmd1);
        cmd1=strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    subcommand.push_back('\0');
    vector<char const*> v( subcommand.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
    {
        v[i] = subcommand[i].c_str();
    }

    fork();
    if(pid==0)
        execvp(subcommand[0].c_str(),v);

}
```

I get this error:

```
main1.cpp: In function ‘void parse(char*)’:
main1.cpp:80:34: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<const char*>’ to ‘char* const*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int execvp(const char*, char* const*)’
```

Tried all permutations with typecasting but just can't get it to work.
What's the problem?

Comment: Besides the near-immediate memory leak on lines 5-6 ? (and ***thank you*** for posting the actual error message). Regardless, see [`execvp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) documentation, then realize you're passing a `std::vector<const char*>` rather than a `char const* arg[]` for the second argument. I haven't tried it yet, but try passing `v.data()` instead. It should at least get you closer.

Comment: That title has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `v` is `vector<char const*>` in the statement `execvp(subcommand[0].c_str(),v);`, while the declaration of evecvp is `int execvp(const char*, char* const*)`.

Comment: How to properly cast it to the required argument ?